# Why does Sheldon Cooper love The Flash?

Tags: character, the-big-bang-theory

There are many superheroes. But Sheldon from *The Big Bang Theory* loves The Flash very much. He loves Batman too. But Why? What's the reason?

Comment: There are many crappy US comedies. But you love The Big Bang Theory very much. You love movies.stackexchange.com. But why? What's the reason?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit there are always practical, explainable reasons why a person would like any given character, no snarkiness needed.

Comment: @cde: There's no "snarkiness". Don't throw names around please. To me, this question comes down to "why does anyone like anything?"

Comment: Because it's funny, like everything else  in comedy

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From [collider.com](http://collider.com/comic-con-big-bang-theory/) on Comic Con 2012:-

> A child asks Parsons, “Why does Sheldon like The Flash?”, Parsons
>   threw the question to the showrunners, and Prady responded that
>   Sheldon liked the Flash because Sheldon was bullied a lot and the
>   Flash was able to run away really fast.

In-universe, The Flash is very pro-science, specially physics and he is  (they are) nerds turned super-hero who can travel faster than light. He is the fastest superhero and one of the oldest too.

Comment: i'm a bit conflicted here by the "can travel faster than light".  Although this shows up in a lot of sci-fi (including both Star Trek and Star Wars) it seems like Sheldon - as a theoretical physicist - would be the most likely to be unable to suspend disbelief in that premise (e.g. travel faster than light + foot powered).

Comment: @Michael Its the (Speed) Force, aint gotta explain s**t. Sheldon can self delude when he needs to.

Comment: @Michael As a theoretical physicist, I think he can appreciate how amazing that ability is. Not knowing physics, a person might think that it's pretty great but not so spectacular to exceed the speed of light.

Comment: Also, the Flash is a scientist, albeit a forensic scientist.